Eigenvalues of a circulant matrix
So we define a circulant matrix as follows. Let the first column be $$a^t = [a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots,a_{n-1}].$$ The other entries are given by circularly permuting the column 1. For example column 2 is given as transpose of $[a_{n-1}, a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n-2}]$.
Let $S_n$ be the set of $n$-periodic sequences. Let $AX = Y$ be a matrix equation where $A$ is circulant.
Let $$\tilde{x},\tilde{y}$$ be the natural extensions of $X$ and $Y$ to sequences in $S_n$.
I have shown the above matrix equation is equivalent to $$[a*\tilde{x}] = \tilde{y}$$
where $a$ is the first column of $A$ and $*$ denotes the convolution of two sequences in $S_n$.
We now claim the eigenvalues of $A$ are exactly the elements in the discrete fourier transform $F[a]$ where $a$ is seen as an element in $S_n$.
One direction is easy to show. You basically see that if $$AX = \lambda X$$ then this to say that $$a*\tilde{x} = \lambda\tilde{x}$$ Doing a DFT on both sides and using the convolution theorem then gives $$F[a]_kF[\tilde{x}]_k = \lambda F[\tilde{x}]_k.$$ This shows basically every eigenvalue is an entry in $F[a]$.
How do we prove the converse? I feel I am missing something obvious but it is what it is.

It’s essentially because all circulant matrices are polynomials in the same permutation matrix. See a previous answer of mine for instance.

I just went thru your proof. It's a very nice proof. Thanks for the details!
